# Does not have http ok status error in angular with webapi

Tags: angular, cors, webapi

i tried to pass my form data from angular to webapi, my webapi works fine by using postman, while passing through angular i am getting below screenshot error for reference. Please see my code and suggest me any modifications.
I Searched in google for Solution, I added proxy.conf.json this also in angular. As of my knowledge i added all details correctly only, Plz suggest me if i done wrong in any place. Help me on this

My WebPAIConfig.cs code:

```
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        //EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        //config.EnableCors();
        //var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        //config.EnableCors(cors);
        config.EnableCors();
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );


    }
```

My WebAPI Cors Code in webConfig.cs:

```
 <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

[image: Error Image in F12]

```
My WebAPI: [Route("api/CLOInfo/SaveUpdateCLODetails/")]
    [AcceptVerbs("POST", "GET")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]CustomModel model)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Succdess");
    } public class CustomModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My ANgular Service call: 
I tried both http and httpclient services also.

```
CLODetailsSave(SaveCLODetails: CLOModels): Observable<Response> {
    let requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs = {
        headers: new Headers({ 'content-type': 'application/json' })
      };

      return this._http.post(this.baseUrl + 'SaveUpdateCLODetails', SaveCLODetails, requestOptions);

    //return this._httpclient.post(this.baseUrl + "SaveUpdateCLODetails", SaveCLODetails);

    // return this._httpclient.post<void>(this.baseUrl + "SaveUpdateCLODetails", SaveCLODetails, {
    //     headers: new HttpHeaders({

    //         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    //         'mode': 'no-cors'
    //     })
    //   });
}
```

My Angular calling Method :

```
this._CLoAPiService.CLODetailsSave(this._CLODetails).subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
})
```

Comment: Try adding `OPTIONS` to `[AcceptVerbs("POST", "GET")]`. [Pre-flight requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) are sent using `OPTIONS` method.

Comment: It is your WebAPI problem, not angular. What version on .net do you use?

Comment: @StanisalvDontsov my .net framework is 4.6.1 and my api works fine by using postman

Comment: @MichaelD  i already added headers

Comment: @chaitanya your API works with postman because the postman doesn't have same-origin policy restrictions. CORS is an issue only related to web browsers, please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS to get the idea.

Comment: @StanisalvDontsov I added Cors error code  in my web.config file also plz see above mentioned code

Comment: @chaitanya: How does the response look in Network tab?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable CORS on your WebApi

```cs
config.EnableCors();
```

For more detailed explanation see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors).

Comment: @chaitanya could you post the code? How you tried it?

Comment: my webapiconfig.cs code:        config.EnableCors();
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: I updated that code also in this question, plz refer

Comment: Try to send `OPTIONS` request with headers: `Origin: your-web-site-address`; `Access-Control-Request-Method: POST`; `Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type` by postman. What do you get?

Answer (score 0):

This video saved my day -

Proxying the API call so that, Angular try to connect through this proxy.

Step 1: Create a file in your project as "proxy.config.json" without double quotes.

Step 2: Put below code in it and save...

```
{
    "/api/*":{
        "target": "http://localhost:80/",
        "secure":"false",
        "logLevel":"debug",
        "changeOrigin":false

    }
}
```

Note: you must put your Back End url.

Step 3: In the "package.json" file, do the below amendment in "start" tag's value only.

```
{
  "name": "front-end",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
    ......
  },
```

here is the Youtube link which might be in older version of Angular for your reference.

[Proxying API call from Angular - Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OjmZPPKaj6A)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32322543)